# Trying to press answer button on main page but window freezes: Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
    #Learning how to create a GUI
    from tkinter import *

    from random import randint

    #Naming the Tk window
    master = Tk()

    #Setting the size of Tk Window
    master.geometry('800x750')


    #Dictionary for the questions
    easy3 = ["Who is CEO of Apple?", "Who is the founder of Facebook?", "Who is the CEO of Google?"]
    easy3_A = ["Tim Cook", "Mark Zuckerburg", "Sundar Pichai"]

    #Defining some variables
    question_number = randint(0,2)

    global score

    question_index = 0

#Procedure
    def callback():
        #A loading... symbol to ease a consumer's concern
        top = Toplevel(master)
        top.geometry('800x750')
        def question_label():
            question_label = Label(top, text = ('Your Question'), bg = 'light blue', font=('Times New Roman',20), highlightbackground='black', width = 25, height = 3)
            question_label.place(x=215,y=125)
            question_label.pack
        def question_text():
            question_text = Label(top, text = easy3[question_number], bg = 'light blue', font=('Times New Roman',16), highlightbackground='black', width = 25, height = 3)
            question_text.place(x=250,y=300)
            question_text.pack
        def answer():
            score = 0
            answer = input('Answer: ')
            if answer == easy3_A[question_number]:
                print('Correct!')
                score = score `enter code here`+ 1
                print('Score = ',score)

            else:
                print('Wrong!')
                print('GAME OVER!')        
        top.configure(background = 'light blue')
        image = PhotoImage(file="STEM_1_final.gif")
        w = Label(top, image=image)
        w.place(x=1,y=1)
        image_2 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_2_final.gif")
        c = Label(top, image=image_2)
        c.place(x=750,y=1)
        image_3 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_3_final.gif")
        a = Label(top, image=image_3)
        a.place(x=1,y=700)
        image_4 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_4_final.gif")
        d = Label(top, image=image_4)
        d.place(x=750,y=700)
        top.title('Question #1')
        b = Button(text="Answer", command=answer)
        b.pack()
        b.place(relx=.5, rely=.9, anchor=CENTER)
        question_text()                                          
        question_label()
        mainloop()



    def main_content():
        #A procedure to create and display the title

        title_label = Label(master, text = 'Can You Beat the Compu-tition?', bg = 'light blue', font=('Times New Roman',40), highlightbackground='black', width = 25, height = 3)
        title_label.pack()

    #Making the background of window light blue
    master.configure(background = 'light blue')

    #Titling the window, "Can you beat the Compu-tition?"
    master.title('Can You Beat the Compu-tition?')

    #Creating the button, and positioning it
    b = Button(text="Next Page", command=callback,)
    b.pack()
    b.place(relx=.5, rely=.75, anchor=CENTER)

    #Invoking the procedure to display the title
    main_content()

    #Uploading all photos for the user interface
    image = PhotoImage(file="STEM_1_final.gif")
    w = Label(master, image=image)
    w.place(x=1,y=1)
    image_2 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_2_final.gif")
    c = Label(master, image=image_2)
    c.place(x=750,y=1)
    image_3 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_3_final.gif")
    a = Label(master, image=image_3)
    a.place(x=1,y=700)
    image_4 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_4_final.gif")
    d = Label(master, image=image_4)
    d.place(x=750,y=700)
    image_5 = PhotoImage(file="STEM_5_final.gif")
    e = Label(master, image=image_5)
    e.place(x=400,y=350, anchor=CENTER)

    #Creating, displaying, positioning, and centering the slogan label
    slogan = Label(master, text = 'A Trivia Game In The STEM Field', bg = 'light blue',font=('Times New Roman',15))
    slogan.place(x=400,y=160, anchor=CENTER)




    #Making this whole piece of code specific to the Tkinter window run
    mainloop()
```

Answer button on Main page is not working if you press it. The window just says "not responding". I don't know what mode to use for the user to input their answer for the question. If you want to input the answer to the question, go to the Python Shell.

Comment: You'll need to trim down your posted code until only a [mcve] remains.

Comment: I need help, project is due at the end of tomorrow

Comment: That doesn't matter to anyone but you. This site is a QA resource for professional and enthusiast programmers, not a last-minute homework completion service.

Comment: Are you intentionally putting functions inside of `callback`? Also, there's no point in calling `pack()` if you immediately call `place`. Use one or the other, not both. Only the last one called will have any effect. Finally, you absolutely should not call `mainloop` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

When you click `Answer` then you execute `input('Answer: ')` in console which blocks all program and `mainloop()` can do its job - receives key/mouse event, sends it to widget, redraws widget, etc. - and it looks like program freeze. After you answer in console and press Enter `mainloop()` can work again.

Use `Tkinter` elements like `Entry` (or build window with `Entry`) to get answer.

See also: [SimpleDialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()

answer = simpledialog.askstring("Answer", "Input answer")
print('Answer:', answer)

root.destroy()
```